# Value error while working with plotly in python

Tags: colors, plotly, bar-chart

Value of 'color' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['Confirmed', 'Deaths', 'Recovered', 'Country/Region'] but received: Brand

Comment: Can you please post a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? We don't know what your df looks like, or what code is leading to the error you're getting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.